# php exec npm run build

Tags: php, npm, exec, shell-exec

On my local development, I use webpack to compile my css and js.
I run `npm run build` in my local terminal to get js/css compiled in my /dist folder.
All of that works awesome.

Now, I want to automate this and have a button in my CMS (Wordpress) that will trigger this `npm run build`.

So what I have now is this, connected to that button:

`$output = shell_exec( "cd where/my/webpack/is && npm run build 2>&1" );`

But I get an npm ERR! I can't seem to get my head around this.
This is the whole error, but I don't think it has anything to do with npm.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn sh
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! path sh
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! ww-platform@2.0.0 build: `npm-run-all -s clean -p build:modern build:legacy`
npm ERR! spawn sh ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ww-platform@2.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Even if I just want to list out all the files in the folder, it fails (telling me that the ls command is not there):

`$output = shell_exec( "cd where/my/webpack/is && ls 2>&1" );`

So I guess my issue is not really with npm, but with the shell_exec or rights?

`php -r 'exec("npm run build");'` works if I run it in the right webpack folder.

Someone some ideas on what I could try next?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Updated the opening posts with more details now @ChrisHaas

Comment: did you find the solution to this problem? @Myle